# Dot-style pagination ideas for Android

Tags: android, pagination

I need to implement a dot-style iOS-like pagination in Android and need help getting started.

I will have anywhere between 1 to 5 dots with an image above each that says "1", "2", "3", "4", "5". clicking on either the dot or the image will take you to the page in question.

I was thinking a recycler view for this or implementing a custom view.

I found this https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator but it seems to be old and it's not available as .aar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using this https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator with gradle, just add this line to your build.graddle:

`compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'`

You must add this to your layout:

`<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/start_indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp" />`

And you can use it on code like this example:

`mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.start_indicator);`
`mIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);`

It looks like this:

[image]

Yow can also change the indicator to match different styles.

Comment: Thank you, Ariel. I will try it out shortly and update this thread.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use that library since it was packaged for gradle by a third-party.

Comment: FYI: I ended up writing a custom view to accomplish this task